# How to increment moths form 6 month?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i am making maintenance system. user can pay 6 months maintenance and there are two part first 6 months and last 6 month if user can pay for first 6 month then it can increment by 6 months and so on

```
        if($request->session()->has('email')){
            $abc=(Session::get('email'));
            $users=Carbon::create(2019,0,30)->addMonths(6); 
            $check=$users->toDatestring();
        }
    if(Maintenance::where(['email', '=', $abc,'maintenance_status', '=', 'PAID'])){
            $check= $users->addMonths(6);
            $check=$users->toDatestring();
            }           
        return view('maintenance',['check'=>$check],['abc'=>$abc]);

i expect to increment from 6 6 months but it can gives second increment not step by step like 2019-1-1 add 6 moths 2019-6-30 and if user can pay first part of maintenance then only increment by 6 months and so..
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

You need to import the namespace for Carbon

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$articles=Article::where("created_at",">", Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))->get();
```

Apply this logic to your scenario.